# Local variable unused in a using statement

Tags: c#

When implementing a using block for the benefit of dispose, such as

```
using (var window = new DialogWindow(Dialogs.MyDialogType))
{
    //Some action here
}
```

I get an obvious resharper / visual studio warning that the local variable window is never used, since it is not mentioned in the using body.

This is technically correct, is there a way to declare variables like this that aren't explicitly used in the using body, but who's dispose method will get called once the using statement terminates?

Call me a sucker for neatness but I do not like having the gray warnings popping up all over the place.

Comment: Why don't you simply surpress the resharper warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't use variable it is enough to do the following

```
//unused variable will not give warning
using (new DialogWindow(Dialogs.MyDialogType))
{
   //Some action here
}
```

Comment: What is an *anonymous variable*? You probably mean an *unused* variable.

Answer (score 8):

Just leave it out if you're not using it.  The below is perfectly valid:

```
using (new DialogWindow(Dialogs.MyDialogType))
{
    //Some action here
}
```

We use this quite often in our infrastructure as we use `IDisposable` to log entry/exit from blocks of code, so we can just do:

```
using (_log.Enter("some block")) {

}
```

There's no variable being assigned to, but the `using` will dispose of the object as normal.

Comment: That's not an abuse... They use the same pattern in mvc HtmlHelper to close forms.

Comment: @spender Fair enough, will edit my text slightly - always felt like it was misusing it a little since it's not _really_ what it's there for

Comment: @James, in a fully managed scenario I found IDisposable makes for extremely readable code and is a highly overlooked feature of the language. I don't consider any alternative use for it abuse.